# python facebook api login

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, mechanize

This website http://wwwhousemag.com.br/vote use facebook api to get some data, i'm trying to authenticate with facebook using mechanize but i'm getting this response:

> **Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /home/house938/public_html/www/includes/class.php:130) in
>   **/home/house938/public_html/www/top50djs/ver_topc4.php** on line
>   **5**

code

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import Cookie
import cookielib
cookiejar =cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
#Facebook login
url = 'https://m.facebook.com'
username = 'mail'
password = 'pass'
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6)')]
browser.open(url)
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.form["email"] = username
browser.form["pass"] = password
browser.submit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.response().read(),'lxml')
name = soup.find('img', class_="by img")
print name['alt'] #returning usename [ok]

url2 = 'http://www.housemag.com.br/www/top50djs/index.php?pg=ver_topc4'
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6)')]

response = browser.open(url2)
print response.get_data() #print erro response like user not logged in
```

This page http://www.housemag.com.br/www/top50djs/index.php?pg=ver_topc4 use facebook name to fill forms.

When i try to login with this link https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=1380514122278764&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.5%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.housemag.com.br%252Fwww%252Ftop50djs%252Findex.php%253Fpg%253Dver_topc3%26state%3Ddedd3b4ff47a4fdf9d8055813e45e06f%26scope%3Demail%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D1380514122278764%26ret%3Dlogin%26sdk%3Dphp-sdk-5.0.0%26logger_id%3D5716f77d-48a6-a3dd-8ad6-791376d2176e&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.housemag.com.br%2Fwww%2Ftop50djs%2Findex.php%3Fpg%3Dver_topc3%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%3Ddedd3b4ff47a4fdf9d8055813e45e06f%23_%3D_&display=page&locale=pt_BR&logger_id=5716f77d-48a6-a3dd-8ad6-791376d2176e

I got a security message on facebook.

How to open this page  http://www.housemag.com.br/www/top50djs/index.php?pg=ver_topc4 with facebook user authenticated?